# How to programmatically name arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a bunch of different arrays and need each one to have specific names(obviously). How do I increment the names of the arrays?

I've tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   var array+i = new Array() ;
}
```

But it obviously doesn't work because `Unexpected token '+'. Expected ';' after var declaration.`

What I want is to have arrays with the following names:

```
array0
array1
array2
array3
...
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix I just don't know how to do it!

Comment: Have you considered an array of arrays?

Comment: Why not just use an array of arrays? [[][][]...]

Comment: @Mate using `eval` for this is an absolutely awful, extremely dangerous idea. Throwing dynamic variables into the global scope is a great way to assist XSS attacks and stomp all over existing libraries. Please don't recommend eval or link w3schools, neither is a good choice.

Comment: @ssube I have only upvote you once, so I'm making a comment to agree as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the arrays as key/values to an object. This way you can keep them all in one place and you don't pollute the global space with *i* number of arrays.

```
var arrObj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = 5; i <= l; i++) {
  arrObj['array' + i] = [];
}
```

Access using `arrObj.array0.push('Bob');` for example.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x75swxcc/1/)

Comment: Well the OP did say he wanted `array0` etc.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using an array of arrays, aka a 2d array. You can do this in two different ways.

First, initialize all the arrays when you create the array container:

```js
var arrays = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 6]
];

for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div>Array" + i + " = " + arrays[i] + "</div>";
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Or, add arrays to the array container using the normal `array[index]` method:

```js
var arrays = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arrays[i] = [i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3];
}

for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div>Array" + i + " = " + arrays[i] + "</div>";
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Then, if you want to access an item in the array, you would call arrays[x][y]. Where x is the array number, and y is the item number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variable names like this. However you can add them to a map:

```
var arrays = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   arrays['array' + i] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the array to be a global variable you should take advantage of the `window` Object like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
  window["array"+i] = [];
}
```

Using this 6 global arrays will be created called:

array0
array1
array2
array3
array4
array5

I believe this is what you are looking for but if you want the arrays as members of another Object then Jivings' and Andy's answers are what you are looking for.